# Regular Expression to get Image Name from File

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract all Image Names and their Paths from a file that was uploaded. I am looking for the proper regex.

The string is massive but a section would look like:

> ..... [{\"name\":\"Aluminum_Black_mat\",\"id\":\"b3281b09-88be-4e9b-9fc2-514cbaae0a0e\",\"backFaceCulling\":true,\"wireframe\":false,\"ambient\":[0.0,0.0,0.0],\"diffuse\":[1.0,1.0,1.0],\"specular\":[0.0,0.0,0.0],\"emissive\":[0.0,0.0,0.0],\"specularPower\":2.56,\"alpha\":1.0,\"diffuseTexture\":{\"name\":\"BlackRailing.jpg\",\"level\":1.0,\"hasAlpha\":false,\"getAlphaFromRGB\":false,\"coordinatesMode\":0,\"isCube\":false,\"uOffset\":0.0,\"vOffset\":0.0,\"uScale\":1.0,\"vScale\":1.0,\"uAng\":0.0,\"vAng\":0.0,\"wAng\":0.0,\"wrapU\":1,\"wrapV\":1,\"coordinatesIndex\":0,\"isRenderTarget\":false,\"renderTargetSize\":0,\"mirrorPlane\":null,\"renderList\":null,\"animations\":[]},\"diffuseFresnelParameters\ .... ETC

In that string there is BlackRailing.jpg. That's what i need to get. If it had a path i would like to get that too. Bascially everything between those quotes and only if it is an image. I have been mucking around on http://www.regexr.com/ for a while and i can't get it to match perfectly. And when i run the following i always get everything before the first quote.

```
preg_match_all('/[ :]".*.(jpe?g|png|bmp)/i', $buffer, $matches);
```

I am really bad with regex, any Help with the right regular expression for php would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks potentially like JSON. Why not try decoding the string and then pull the relevant data from the object / array?

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('/:\\?"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp))/i', $str, $matches); print_r($matches[1]);`. But since it is most likely JSON, I'd suggest using JSON parser.

Comment: It is a JSON file, but the file can be between 5-500mb large. I'm not sure if that's wise for the server to store all of that as a Variable. Currently i am just parsing line by line looking for file names. @stribizhev that almost worked, i removed the first \\ as i realized that all the quotes are escaped and they shouldnt be as they aren't in the file... now my array is arriving as:
[":\"BlackRailing.jpg","BlackRailing.jpg"] .. Any way to remove :\" from the first one and only have just that? Currently using `preg_match('/:?"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp))/i', $buffer, $matches);`

Comment: Take a look at this article http://soyuka.me/streaming-big-json-files-the-good-way/ that explains how to read a big json file as a stream (or write your own parser).  if you need to remove the backslashes before quotes, use sed in the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you treat a JSON file as a text file, you can use a preg_replace approach like this *assuming that there are no spaces between `:` and the value*:

```
preg_match('/(?<=:")[^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp)/i', $buffer, $matches);
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP0lU1/1)

The `(?<=:")` look-behind just checks for `:"` but does not capture it.

Note if you have a single space in-between the `:` and `"`, you can use `'/(?<=:[ ]")[^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png|bmp)/i'` regex, but if there may be more, you will need a capturing group approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was surprised that i could preg_match the whole file even if it was that large, json_decoding it was putting an out of memory error. Regarless you solution worked and thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked, please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you. [See How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)